# ComboBox in AS3 'eats' last letter

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a problem with flash component ComboBox. When i wont to save a name in ComboBox its always without last letter!?

Here is the code:

```
    var input_name:String;
    text_field.addEventListener (TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT, text_input);
    button.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, save);
    function save (e:MouseEvent):void
    {
      text_field.visible = true;
      text_field.adddEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, save_text);
    }

    function text_input(e:TextEvent):void
      {
        input_name = text_field.text;
      }

    function save_text(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
       var keyPressed:String = e.keyCode.toString();
       if (keyPressed == "13")
        {
           combo.addItem({label:input_name, data:input_name});
        }
     }
```

So when i enter 'foo' in text field and press ENTER it saves in combobox just 'fo'...

Thx for answers :)

Answer (score 0):

`TextEvent.TEXT_INPUT` is dispatched before the value has changed.

`Event.CHANGE` is dispatched after the value has changed.

This will work, including handling the <kbd>enter</kbd> key.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

var input_name:String;

text_field.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, text_input);
text_field.addEventListener("enter", save);
button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, save);

function text_input(e:Event):void
{
    input_name = text_field.text;
}

function save(e:*):void
{
    text_field.visible = true;
    combo.addItem({label:input_name, data:input_name});
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it's `Event.CHANGE` you are looking for.